I'm not being able to print to pdf big webpages
i'm not being able to print the whole page to pdf using the microsoft print to pdf, it cuts part of it.
The page that i'm trying to print is in this site: https://eportugal.gov.pt/empresas/Services/Online/Pedidos.aspx?service=CCP
In the blank search box the code to access the doc is: 6288-8056-1145
It seems to happen with only big documents. If anyone know any kind of solution i would be gratefull.
Edit: Just adding some images that i hope to get clear my doubt about this.
Print wizard. The green line wraping the data is only for you to see the data difference between the two prints, so you can know that part of the content is being cutted. 
This should be the last piece of information that should appear before the footer of webpage

Most straightforward decision would be to use chrome with webpage capturing extension

@TowsifAhamedLabib Do you know any good one?

@Community I added some prints to try clarify

There are browsers such as Firefox that have their own print dialog, with settings to ensure the page layout is optimal.
In the example below, one can use Fit to page width to avoid cutting off part of the page, but there are other options to improve layout. For example, Simplified Format removes some extraneous sections of the web page, page margins can be set, etc.


As you wanted a suggestion about Chrome extension, I use this https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl , works like a charm.
You didn't explicitly mention which browser you're using, from the image my guess is Microsoft edge. But from the previous answer, "Fit to page" and "Simplified Format" should fix your problem with Microsoft print to pdf.

Edge is a Web editor so If you understand the page structure you can edit it as you wish in say English or Original Language.


What you may NOT be aware of is that PDF cannot be an infinite length,
there is a natural 5 m UNITS limitation. So a railway "5 Mile Diagram" must be scaled to 1 meter per mile!
A common question I get is "How do I cut my long PDF into manageable NON failing pieces?" since Opera Browser will spew out unlimited ? lengths.
One answer is to use a printer with say 2 m long pages. Another is use a viewer that does not show gaps! but gapless may be impossible as you may need 2 pages even when reduced in scale.


Another problem with long PDF pages is even if it fits into 5 m the whole page in a viewer takes longer for rendering than viewing all 14 pages at once !
Your best bet is to use the browser editing facility and add page breaks into the HTML. Then pages can be regular but with contents split where needed.

The issue here is that is not a programmable task it requires human editing for human consumption so then it becomes an application training question not a user programming one.
OPERA browser can save page full length just beware when the output is over 5 m you need to split that page somewhere into no more than 5 m lengths and ideally multiple A4/Letter pages.
